# workflow triggering automatically without editing the item in list

Tags: workflow, email, 2016

Based on my conditions given in the **workflow**, is there any way that mail will go automatically without the item being edited once its created.

```
if item  == "" && item2 >=today
```

email "anyone" until item is entered

Answer (score 1):

No out of the box solution.

You need to create custom solution for the same like Timer job or Visual Studio workflow.

PFA url to create and deploy timer job.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/634208/Create-and-Deploy-Custom-Timer-Job-Definition-in-S

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **action** of `wait for a field change` and then test your condition.